# Javascript seems to have disabled my Ctrl+V function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to left-justify a cursor when I click into a textbox, because the textbox has a mask on it and sometimes a user will paste into the center of the box causing all sorts of issues.

I admit I didn't write this, nor am I fluent in either C#, dot net or Javascript, so I'm having trouble understanding why it's not working.

My script looks like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //Add this to the textbox: OnFocus="txtEPro_OnFocus()" 
    function txtEPro_OnFocus() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
        elem.value = "";
        elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

        var event = event || window.event;
        if (event.button == '0') {
            // it was a right click
            setTimeout(function () {
                elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
            }, 0);

        }
        // alert("Hello there"); 
    }

</script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).mousedown(function () {
        if (event.button == 2 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= txtePro.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        alert('right click not allowed');
        return false;
        }
        if (event.button == 2 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= TBAccountNum.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= TBAccountNum.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        alert('right click not allowed');
        return false;
        }
        if (event.button == 1 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= txtePro.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        //alert('left click not allowed');
        return false;
        }
        if (event.button == 1 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= TBAccountNum.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= TBAccountNum.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        //alert('left click not allowed');
        return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is supposed to left-justify the cursor, as well as eliminate the ability of the user to right-click to paste data into the field.

Running this locally works fine.  When I upload it to my server, it doesn't paste anything.

Is there something obvious that's missing here?

Comment: " When I upload it to my server, it doesn't paste anything."  What do you mean by doesnt paste anything?

Comment: I mean that Ctrl+V doesn't work.  If I comment out the piece that is supposed to eliminate the right-click mouse button, I can paste it in that way, but Ctrl+V doesn't paste anything.